# IExceptionHandler in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I'm trying to use the new `IExceptionHandler` of .NET 8.

I have an `ExceptionHandler` class:

```
public class ExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        switch (ex)
        {
            case ArgumentNullException:
                await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new ProblemDetails
                    {
                        Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
                        Type = ex.GetType().Name,
                        Title = ex.Message,
                        Detail = ex.Message,
                        Instance = $"{context.Request.Method} {context.Request.Path}"
                    });
                break;

            default:
                await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new ProblemDetails
                    {
                        Status = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                        Type = ex.GetType().Name,
                        Title = ("Internal server error"),
                        Detail = ("Internal server error"),
                        Instance = $"{context.Request.Method} {context.Request.Path}"
                    });
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And in the startup.cs I've configure the service as:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // add services to the DI container
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
// configure strongly typed settings object
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

// configure DI for application services
services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

services.AddCors();
services.AddControllers();

services.AddExceptionHandler<ExceptionHandler>();
services.AddProblemDetails();

services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "APIs", Version = "v1" });
});
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
app.UseExceptionHandler(opt => { });

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1"));
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// global cors policy
app.UseCors(x => x
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader());

app.UseEndpoints(x => x.MapControllers());
        }
    }
```

I have an API controller:

```
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private IUserService _userService;

    public UsersController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpPost("authenticate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest model)
    {
        try 
        { 
            var response = await  _userService.Authenticate(model);
            return Ok(response);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("hello world!");
        }
    }
}
```

The error is not being handled by the `IExceptionHandler`.

[image: .NET8]

Comment: try just throwing exception in controller action. I dont know but may your _userService handles exceptions gracefully. And never throws excception.

Comment: Can you add your full app startup code?

Comment: Jepozdemiz I tried didn't work either

Comment: If you have app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); remove it - it prevents your exception handler from running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting this from the startup.cs solved the problem

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing few configuration settings :

```
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
```

and

```
app.UseExceptionHandler();
```

So example `Program.cs` would look like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<ExceptionHandler>();
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseExceptionHandler();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


public class ExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        switch (ex)
        {
            case ArgumentNullException:
                await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new ProblemDetails
                {
                    Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
                    Type = ex.GetType().Name,
                    Title = ex.Message,
                    Detail = ex.Message,
                    Instance = $"{context.Request.Method} {context.Request.Path}"
                });
                break;
            default:
                await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new ProblemDetails
                {
                    Status = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                    Type = ex.GetType().Name,
                    Title = ("Internal server error"),
                    Detail = ("Internal server error"),
                    Instance = $"{context.Request.Method} {context.Request.Path}"
                });
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already had them, i updated my post showing all the startup.cs

Comment: Well not sure why , but I have the same setup and it works - did you let you exception to be thrown and set up break point in TryHandleAsync() ?

Comment: it did not enter